# Get data from FE user into own EXT in TYPO3 8.7.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Heyho, I am trying to get data, (i.e. the uid) from the current logged in user who is using the site.

In TYPO3 7.6.X it was very easy. You just had to use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user` to get the data. In TYPO3 8.7.x it is a little bit more complicated. It should work with `$frontendUserAspect = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class)->getAspect('frontend.user');
$frontendUserAspect->get('id')`. But in my case it does not.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Reevo\ReevoElearning\Output;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\UserAspect;

class FlexformValue {
    function field($content, $conf) {
// TSFE USER ID
$frontendUserAspect = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class)->getAspect('frontend.user');
$frontendUserAspect->get('id'); 
$test = $frontendUserAspect;
echo $test;
return "$test";
    }
}
```

I get the following error: 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context' is not found or something like this.
But if I am deleting this line `use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context;` it is looking for the same file in my namespace folder. Does anyone know how to get it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user` is still available in TYPO3 8.7. I think it has been deprecated in 9, but won't be removed until 10. The FrontendUserAspect was introduced in 9.4 I think and probably `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context` was as well, so the error is correct. You should still use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user` in TYPO3 8.7.

Official documentation:

- Changelog: Introducing the Context API in 9.4: [Feature: #85389 - Context API for consistent data handling](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85389-ContextAPIForConsistentDataHandling.html)
- Official documentation for [Context API and Aspects](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html)

> As for TYPO3 v9, the old properties can be used the same way as before, but will trigger a PHP E_USER_DEPRECATED error.

Answer (score 0):

The context-API was introduced in TYPO3 9. If the documentatin is correct, the context-API wasn't part of TYPO3 8.7.

```
// will work in TYPO3 9.5
$frontendUserAspect = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class)->getAspect('frontend.user');
$frontendUserAspect->get('id')
```